# Open a file in linux machine on a Mac Text Editor

Tags: linux, macos, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, text-editor

I have problem with my **FTP client**, so that's not an option.

---

I SSH into my Ubuntu server, and tried to open up a file with my Mac Text editor application such **Text Edit**, or **Sublime Text**.

Is there a command that will help me do that ?

I would do this - if I am on a Mac

```
open -a TextEdit /home/forge/rsm/resources/views/layouts/internal/master2/dashboard.blade.php
```

Any directions on this will be great !!

Answer (score 0):

Try using sshfs. Mount the Linux drive on your system and then you will be able to use the folders like there were local. This will allow you to open the file.